# Rendering HTML on Iphone

Tags: iphone, html, epub

I'm planning ePub/HTML rendering system on Iphone. I’m not experience in programming on this platform and I would like to ask what is the better way to start in this topic on IPhone platform. I would like to render ePub which is HTML+CSS subpart but I don’t want simple web page view – I need interaction with text and some way to add adorners like underline or others to text – because of this simple html rendering control is not enough. Can anyone point me in right direction where to start looking?

Answer (score 1):

ePubs are nothing but archives... where HTML/CSS javascript is embedded into it.. For those interactions to work you would need it to render it on a webview.

There are some "coding rules" with javascript css html you might need to follow to have a nice interactive experience with underlining of text and all that...

If you are looking for an own ePub reading app
You can have a look at this...

I am rendering an ePub by unzipping it and then rendering the contents in an UIwebView.

I am working on finding a more dynamic approach. But this should get you started..

https://github.com/zeroCoder1/Epub-Reader